# Java compressing some code

Tags: java, variables, optimization

Very new to Java and I am looking to change the following to allow the same variable call to occur only once.

The second "b" variable is only called during rectangle and triangle. This does work just want to see if I can get that one extra line out of the main.

The "b" variable can not be moved out from the if statements as the program will not start as the user will only enter the a variable.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("? ");
        String word = in.next();    
        Shape s = null;
        while (!word.equals("quit")) {
            double a = in.nextDouble();
            if (word.equals("triangle")){
                double b = in.nextDouble();
                s = new Shapet (a, b);
            }else if (word.equals("rectangle")){
                double b = in.nextDouble();
                s = new Shaper (a, b);          
            }else if (word.equals("square")){
                s = new Shapes (a);             
            }else if (word.equals("circle")){
                s = new Shapec (a);             
            }else if (word.equals("pentagon")){
                s = new Shapep (a);             
            }
            System.out.printf("Area of %s = %.2f\n", s, s.area());      
            System.out.print("? ");
            word = in.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as you did with `s` you can put `b` out side the loop.

Comment: Also consider using switch with String rather than this huge number of if/elseif blocks. This will make your code more readable as well. You also said you have just started with Java... why Shapet class instead of Triangle class that implements Shape interface? Having classes like Triangle, Rectangle, Square etc will greatly improve readability.

Comment: Check out the code using switch below... :)

Comment: And for readabiliy, please name your `Shapet` class `Triangle`, `Shaper` `Rectangle` etc.

Comment: I can not have the b variable outside like the a as it will then wait for that input which will never happen.

The classes are to find the area of the shapes, not really required I think for this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to reduce lines of code, possibly you can go for inline code:

```
double a;
while (!word.equals("quit")) {
  a = in.nextDouble();
  if (word.equals("triangle")) {
    s = new Shapet(a, in.nextDouble());
  } else if (word.equals("rectangle")) {
    s = new Shaper(a, in.nextDouble());
  } else if (word.equals("square")) {
    s = new Shapes(a);
  }
  // ...
}
```

**P.S.** Avoid declaring variables inside loops

Answer (score 1):

You could use switch which will not make the code shorter but more readable:

```
String word = in.next();    
Shape s = null;
while (!word.equals("quit")) {
   double a = in.nextDouble();
   switch(word) {
    case "triangle":
        s = new Shapet (a, in.nextDouble());
        break;
    case "rectangle":
        s = new Shaper (a, in.nextDouble());    
        break;      
    case "square":
        s = new Shapes (a); 
        break;            
    case "circle":
        s = new Shapec (a);  
        break;           
    case "pentagon":
        s = new Shapep (a);      
        break;       
   }
   word = in.next(); 
 }
```

Comment: I also prefer this method. Lots of whitespace so you can directly see the code that does the work.

Comment: I think this is more readable, too. But it doesn't match OP's behavior. The double and string reads need to occur inside the loop so the reading can advance. (As is here, `word` is never changed, so it'll be an infinite loop.) And the second `nextDouble()` call (for `b`) is only supposed to happen for triangles and rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

If I where you I would leave the code as is and simply change the variable names to something which is more appropriate.

I would let each chunk within your `if` statements handle their own variables. This would make the code easier to read.

Something like so:

```
 while (!word.equals("quit")) {
        if (word.equals("triangle")){
            double base = in.nextDouble();   //You could maybe print out 'Enter base length, or something like that, same goes for the one below.
            double height = in.nextDouble();
            s = new Shapet (base, height);
        }
```

In this case I am *assuming* that you want to calculate the area of some shape and maybe render it. If this is not the case, then maybe renaming `Shapet` to something which gives more information on the purpose of the class might also help.

Keep in mind that although you should not write bloated code, readability is key. Thus, if you need to take an extra couple of lines to make your code easier to follow, you should, in most cases, take that path.

Comment: That is increasing the lines as I would be repeating the a variable for all of them. But thanks :)

Comment: @RichardLawton: Yes your code would be more readable. Seeing `double d =...` in code to me does not really make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the variables are inside the if and they are all local. So you can take them out of the if. Because you are studying Java, I'd like to recommend you to change the class name to make it more Object Oriented. You also can use enum for the ShapeType. I think it's a bit far your question but I hope this help you to have a better view (Pls also change the variable "a", "b" to the meaningful one. I still keep it in my sample).

```
enum ShapeType {
        triangle("triangle"), rectangle("rectangle"), square("square"), circle("circle"), pentagon("pentagon");
        private String value;
        ShapeType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }


 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     String word = in.next();  
     //check the type is ok or not
     ShapeType shapeType = ShapeType.valueOf(word);

     String quit = "quit";
     Shape s = null;
     double a = in.nextDouble();
     double b = in.nextDouble();

     while (!word.equals(quit)) {
        switch(shapeType) {
         case triangle:
             s = new Triangle(a, b);
             break;
         case rectangle:
             s = new Ractangle (a, b);    
             break;      
         case square:
             s = new Square (a); 
             break;            
         case circle:
             s = new Circle (a);  
             break;           
         case pentagon:
             s = new Pentagon (a);      
             break;       
         default:
             System.out.println("Invalid shape! Pls retry");

         }
      }
```